# Monodevelop database browser on windows?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am using Monodevelop 2.4.1 with mono 2.8  on Windows Vista . Despite the Monodevelop website having [screenshot of the Database Browser](http://monodevelop.com/@api/deki/files/204/=ss-database.png) .... I cannot find any menu item , sidebar, or pane for database browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database browser addin for MonoDevelop is not available for the windows version.

Comment: Do you know of any future plans etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. May I ask what type of database do you need it for? Aren't there other database browsers for it?